# multiple web servers/services on a single host machine... sharing an ssl cert?

Tags: apache, web-services, iis, ssl, ssl-certificate

We're developing a C#/.NET WCF web service that needs be installed on an (enterprise) customer's machine, which may or may not have Apache/IIS running as well.

Communication with our service has to be secured with SSL, but what if the existing Apache/IIS is already using an SSL cert for this address? Can we share it since the host is the same?

For example:

```
Host:                        sasquatch.ourcustomer.com
Their existing stuff:        Apache or IIS is running on port 80
Our newly installed stuff:   Our service is running on port 9999
```

If Apache/IIS has its own cert, should/can we use it too?

If not, what should we do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A certificate identifies a host and not a service. It is independent from the port you use or the application providing the service. If you have multiple services on the same host it is still the same host, so you can use the same certificate.

Comment: Thanks.

(lame 15-character minimum comment length makes it difficult to thank someone)

;)